# Hamiltonian circuit for a family of graphs

Tags: search-algorithms, strings, hamiltonian-path, hamiltonian-circuit

For $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$, let $S_n = \{w\mid w \in \Sigma^{*} \land |w| = n\}$.

Let $C_n \subset \Sigma^{*}$ be the language of circular strings that contain as substrings all elements of $S_n$.
For instance,  $bbaaaababaabbbba \in C_4$

I have formulated the problem of finding the subset of $C_n$, formed by the circular strings with the **smallest size** ($=2^n$), as the problem of finding all hamiltonian circuits on the graph that has the elements of $S_n$ as vertices, and edges connecting all pairs of vertices $s_i$ and $s_j$ such that $s_i = xw$ and $s_j = wy$, with $w \in \Sigma^{n-1}$ and $x,y \in \Sigma$.

For the example above, the graph could look like this:

[image]

My question:

> Would there be a polynomial-time solution for the hamilton circuit problem restricted to this family of graphs?

Comment: It feels like this might be related to [$n$-ary Grey codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#n-ary_Gray_code), which are a way of enumerating the length-$k$ strings from an $n$-symbol alphabet  such that adjacent elements of the enumeration differ by exactly one character. That's not quite what you want but it's similar. (Yuval's answer appeared while I was writing this comment; I'm posting the comment anyway in case it turns out to be useful.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This graph is known as a [de Bruijn graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_graph), and its Hamiltonian circuits are known as [de Bruijn sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence). Both are well understood (for example, we know exactly how many of these exist).

Comment: In particular, every de Bruijn graph is Hamiltonian.